# Coheight of an ideal generated by $n$ elements

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $R$ be a noetherian ring, and let $I$ be a proper ideal in $R$. If $I$ is generated by $n$ elements, we have by Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem that the height of $I$ is at most $n$.

> Is it true that $\dim R-\dim R/I\le n$?

(Note that $\operatorname{ht}I\le\dim R-\dim R/I$.)

Comment: The inequality does not hold for a Noetherian ring, in general, and the answer provides a counterexample. However, it holds for local rings (see also the answer), and for finitely generated algebras over a field which are integral domains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. Let $R=\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}[X]$, and $I=(2X-1)$, where $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ is the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ localized at the prime ideal $(2)$. Then $R/I$ is a field.

Another cheap counter-example is $R=k\times \mathbb{Z}[X]$ where $k$ is any field. Let $I$ generated by $(0,1)$, i.e., $I=\{0\}\times \mathbb{Z}[X]$. Then $R/I$ is a field. However $\dim R=2$.

It is true for a Noetherian local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m})$. Suppose $\dim R/I=r$. Then we can find $x_1,\dots,x_r$ whose images generate an ideal of definition of $R/I$, that is, $\mathfrak{m}/I$ is minimal over $(x_1,\dots,x_r)/I$. Say $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ generate $I$. Then $\mathfrak{m}$ is minimal over $(x_1,\dots,x_r,y_1,\dots,y_n)$, so $\dim R\leq r+n=\dim R/I+n$.

Comment: So the statement ". For R Noetherian, the dimension of R / I is, by Krull's principal ideal theorem, at least dim R − n" is incorrect on the wikipedia page for "commutative ring"

Comment: Yes. The counter-example is given as above.

Comment: The reason I was asking is because I wanted to show that $\mathbb Z [x,y] / \langle f \rangle $ could not have dimension 1 for any f in $\mathbb Z[x,y]$ given that I know the dimension of $\mathbb Z[x,y]$ is 3. Is there another way to see this ?

Comment: If you know that every maximal ideal has height 3 in your ring, the problem is solved.