# Minimal number of generators of ideal versus codimension

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $A$ be a Noetherian local ring of dimension $n$, $I$ be an ideal such that $\dim A/I=m$. By [Krull’s principal ideal theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem) $I$ cannot be generated by less than $n-m$ elements.

Is there a criterion when can $I$ be generated by exactly $n-m$ elements? When it is not possible, can the discrepancy be bounded?

Comment: Krull’s theorem says $\dim A/(x) \geq \dim A-1$ for any non-unit $x$. By induction, if $I=(x_1, \ldots, x_r)$ is a proper ideal then $\dim A/I \geq \dim A - r$. It follows that $r\geq \dim A - \dim A/I = n-m$. @user26857

Comment: Think the argument works for any Noetherian $A$, including non-local. @user26857

Comment: I think [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/148004) also contains a proof of the claim

Comment: @aaaacb Certainly not! If $A=K[[X]][Y]$ and $I=(XY-1)$, then $1<2-0$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake @user26857! Think for $A$ **local** Noetherian it ($\dim A/(x) \geq \dim A-1 $ for any non-unit $x$) is true, right? (And agree even if it is true, it does not follow directly from Krull’s PIT.)

Answer (score 1):

Think I figured out. Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be the maximal ideal of $A$ and $k=A/\mathfrak{m}$ be the residual field. Then the minimal number of generators for $I$ is, by Nakayama, $\dim_k I/I\mathfrak{m}$. So the “criterion” is simply:
$$
\dim_k I/I\mathfrak{m} = \dim A - \dim A/I.
$$

There is probably no general further refinement(s). For example when $I=\mathfrak{m}$ then the above becomes $\dim A=\dim_{A/\mathfrak{m}} \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$. These are [regular local rings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_local_ring) which are themselves subject of intensive study.